# Handling iOS8 interactive notifications interrupting our app

Tags: notifications, ios8, interactive

We're currently testing our existing app against the iOS8 Beta 5.

While testing the new iOS interactive notifications (as implemented in iMessage), when these arrive while focus is on our app, our app is not automatically interrupted. The app continues to run until the player has responded to the notification.

Our app is an action game, so you can see the problem with it continuing to run without user input.

Is there any way we can make our app recognise the incoming notification, and enter a paused state?

I had been expecting iOS8 to handle that gracefully and suspend the app, but it doesn't do this, at least not in Beta 5. So I assume that Apple are expecting developers to implement this themselves on a per-app basis?

Comment: Having the same issue. There don't appear to be any notifications or UIAppDelegate methods that get called. Please post an answer if you find one.